# QMediaPlayer app not responding when play many times in a short duration

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I created a default Qt GUI app, I added `void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* ev);` in the mainwindow class, when user presses the space, the app will plays the sound (ok) but when the user press many times in a short duration, the app will not respond. I don't know why? Help me, please!

.pro file:

```
QT       += core gui multimedia

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
    res.qrc
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMediaPlayer>

namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();
  void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* ev);
private:
  Ui::MainWindow *ui;
  QMediaPlayer mp;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QKeyEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{ ui->setupUi(this); }

MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; }

void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* ev) {
  switch(ev->key()) {
  case Qt::Key_Space: {
    mp.setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/Fireworks.wav"));
    mp.play();
    break;
  }
  }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  MainWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

(Note: I did upload mainwindow.ui. res.qrc here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mp.setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/Fireworks.wav"));`

Do not set the media unnecessarily, as the mediaplayer doesnt check internally *"Oh the media is the same I am going to be clever"*

Rather you want to start the media from the beginning when its key is pressed again. The simplest solution is to have a boolean which indicate if the media is set.

```
  case Qt::Key_Space: 
  {
    if(!is_media_set)
    {
        mp.setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/Fireworks.wav"));
        is_media_set = true;
    }
    mp.setPosition(0);
    mp.play();
    break;
  }
```

If several keys trigger different sounds replace the boolean with `current_media_key` to indicate the last media loaded.

Comment: the answer is mp.setPosition(0);

Answer (score 1):

To setMedia, the documentation says:

> Setting this property to a null QMediaContent will cause the player to
>   discard all information relating to the current media source and to
>   cease all I/O operations related to that media.

Each time one presses space again, the media file has to be loaded from disk, it might be a good idea to load it once in the constructor or an initialization method, to save the loading time (access to a hard disk is always slow)

To run the sound again, add also `setPosition(0)` before calling `play()`.

Comment: if setMedia in the constructor or some where same, the sound will just play only one time at first. I don't know why.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you call "setPosition(0)" before "play()"?

Comment: Setting setMedia many times will cause of not responding. -> set one time only

Comment: If no adding setPosition(0), there are just some first time I can hear the sound, with setPosition(0), the app runs correctly

Comment: if I press the space when mp.state() is PlayingState, the sound will replay, but when the mp.state() is StoppedState, there are no sound

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best answer, but this is my final result:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* ev) {
  switch(ev->key()) {
  case Qt::Key_Space: {
    qDebug() << mp.mediaStatus() << mp.state();
    if(mp.state() == QMediaPlayer::StoppedState) {
      mp.setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/sounds/Fireworks.wav"));
    }
    mp.setPosition(0);
    mp.play();
    break;
  }
  }
}
```